# State-machine : How to change state without external event (transient state)?

Tags: state-machine

The scenario:
I have a simple state machine:

**Happy path:**

```
Uninitialized->Initialized->InProgress->Done
```

**Unhappy path:**

```
Uninitialized->Initialized->Error
```

Simply put, I need to cause a transition (either into InProgress or in Error state) **without an external event/trigger**. I.e. Initialized state should immediately result in one of those states.

Questions:

1. Is it OK to cause state transition from within **Initialized.Enter()** ?
2. I could use **state guards** to do this, but I'd rather not have non-trivial logic in the state guard (and initialization can very well be complex).
3. If it is NOT OK, how can I do it differently?
4. Should I just take this decision out of he FSM all together and have some other component cause the appropriate transition? But then, wouldn't I still have to call that external component from within **Initialized.Enter()** ? so it solves nothing?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647631/c-state-machine-design/1651187

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a state machine, next state is a combinatorial logic function of both input and current state.

In the case you are describing, the same cause (`Initialized` state) seems to be able to trigger two different effects (either `InProgress` or `Error` state). I guess that there is a hidden input whose value makes the difference. I also guess that this input is received during transition from `Uninitialized` to `Initialized`.

Therefore I would have a different model:

```
Uninitialized -> Successfully initialized -> InProgress -> Done
             \
              `-> Failed Initialization -> Error
```

Possibly combining `Successfully initialized` with `InProgress` and `Failed initialization` with `Error`.

---

**EDIT**: From your comment, I understand that the hidden input actually is the result of an action (a device initialization). Taking your model, I assume that initialization takes place while in `Initialized` state (let's call it `Initializing`). This way, the result from the device is your external event which will trigger transition either to `InProgress` or to `Error`.

So keep your state machine and simply add the result of `device.Initialize()` to the list of inputs or external events.